# unbound method must be called with instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Tags: python, python-2.7, camera, raspberry-pi3

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera
camera.hflip = True #camera ad effetto specchio (flip orizzontale)

def registra_video():
    camera.start_recording('video.h264')
    camera.start_preview()

def stop_video():
    camera.stop_recording()
    camera.stop_preview()

while True:
    registra_video()
```

This is a first sketch, then the function will be maneged by the output of a motion sensor, but now i've put the while in loop to try to start recording and the preview, but i get the error explained in the title. Why?

P.s sorry i'm noob in python and raspberry development.

Comment: `camera = PiCamera()` I think.

Comment: omg what a stupid error! Now it works, thanks.